# Keras RNN - ValueError when checking Input

Tags: keras, lstm

I recently got a Nvidia Card and wanted to try LSTM-Models with the new GPU-Support. Sadly I do not know much about LSTMs. And I build this little model to test it:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer, StandardScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))

data = pd.read_excel("./data/google_data.xlsx", header=0)
X = data.drop("Close", axis=1)
y = data["Close"]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=10, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(4,1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

print(model.summary())

normalizer = StandardScaler()
normalizer.fit(X)
X = normalizer.fit_transform(X)

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=64, epochs=40, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

I always get an ValueError, I have tried the Inputshape from the Keras Docs w ith (batch_size,timesteps,features) but I still get the same **ValueError**.

[image: Error Traceback]

I guess it is probably a quite dumb problem, but a newbie like me could need some help. Thanks!

Comment: Keras is expecting a 3D input shape of (None, 4, 1) and it's getting a 2D shape of (2515,4).  Note that "None" in this context means "any value".  Try `input_shape=(4,) not (4,1)`.  This should produce a 2D input shape of (None, 4).

Comment: Try to reshape all `X`s by `X = X.reshape((-1, 4, 1))`.